# What do the stackoverflow numbers mean in Visual Studio 2012 Update 4?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just updated Visual Studio 2012 with Update 4.

To my pleasant surprise, I just discovered it now integrates stackoverflow.

But I'm not sure what the numbers mean after signing in. See the picture below:

[image]

I gathered the first one is reputation.

What's the second?

Third I assume was mail / notifcations. But I do not have any on the website...

What's the fourth?

I did try and find the [notes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872520) regarding what changed in Update 4. But I couldn't find anything about stackoverflow being integrated.

**Update 1:** I figure the second is the amount of reputation you have earned this month.

**Update 2:** As Jehof pointed out in the comments, this is something added by VSCommands. It appeared after I updated, so I assumed it was part of Update 4. Sorry for getting anyone's hopes up.

Comment: You just made me start the VS Update just to see if this is really the case...

Comment: Yep, I really need this too :) Updating..

Comment: this is not from Visual Studio. StackOverflow is integrated by VSCommands

Comment: @Jehof Woops, sorry. I just updated and it appeared after. So I just assumed it was in Update 4. Sorry for getting everyone's hopes up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's from VSCommands you will find description [here](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Tags/release).

Answer (score 2):

For the lazy not following @Akrem 's [link:](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Tags/release)

`Reputation changes, messages and mentions from last 30 days are shown:`

```
✉ - messages
★ - favourite questions
✄ - revisions
● - badges
```